# Pear telling me to upgrade and then "Nothing to upgrade"

Tags: php, terminal, pear

I'm trying to install PHPUnit. I'm getting an error message that I need to update the version of Pear, but then when I try to do it, it says Nothing to update.

Any ideas what's happening here?

[image]

```
UPDATE - this is the output on `pear list` 


    =========================================
    Package             Version State
    Archive_Tar         1.3.7   stable
    Auth                1.6.4   stable
    Auth_RADIUS         1.0.7   stable
    Auth_SASL           1.0.4   stable
    Benchmark           1.2.8   stable
    Cache_Lite          1.7.9   stable
    Console_CommandLine 1.1.3   stable
    Console_Getopt      1.3.1   stable
    Crypt_CHAP          1.5.0   stable
    DB                  1.7.13  stable
    File_Passwd         1.1.7   stable
    File_SMBPasswd      1.0.3   stable
    HTML_Common         1.2.5   stable
    HTML_QuickForm      3.2.12  stable
    HTTP_Client         1.2.1   stable
    HTTP_Request        1.4.4   stable
    Log                 1.12.6  stable
    MDB                 1.3.0   stable
    MDB2                2.4.1   stable
    Mail                1.2.0   stable
    Mail_Mime           1.8.1   stable
    Net_DIME            1.0.2   stable
    Net_POP3            1.3.8   stable
    Net_SMTP            1.5.2   stable
    Net_Socket          1.0.10  stable
    Net_URL             1.0.15  stable
    Net_Vpopmaild       0.3.2   beta
    PEAR                1.9.2   stable
    Payment_DTA         1.4.1   stable
    SOAP                0.12.0  beta
    Structures_Graph    1.0.4   stable
    XML_Parser          1.3.4   stable
    XML_RPC2            1.0.8   stable
    XML_Util            1.2.1   stable
```

Comment: try pear update-channels

Comment: What's the output of `pear list`?

Comment: @zerocrates I posted the output of pear list in the OP

Comment: When you ran `pear list`, did you use the same "/Applications/MAMP/..." path you used for the other commands? The output indicates that you *do* have PEAR 1.9.2, but it's possible that you're looking at the installed packages for your system PEAR.

Comment: @zerocrates I used the /Applications/MAMP/ path...that's what so weird. I also tried it with sudo and another user. same result. I heard through PEAR mail list that someone had a similar problem with PHPUnit on Mac, but they didn"t know how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and in my case it was because phpunit has a dependency of the pear.symfony.com channel. The following worked for me:

```
pear uninstall phpunit
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
pear install phpunit/phpunit
```

Without the symfony channel, pear did only install in version 3.5.15. After adding the channel, i got 3.7.7.

Answer (score 2):

First, clear the cache. Stale package information may be in there.

```
$ pear clear-cache
$ pear upgrade pear
```

Then, verify you get the correct remote package information - it should show 1.9.2:

```
$ pear remote-info pear
Latest      1.9.2
Installed   1.9.1
...
```

If the latest is not 1.9.2, you've got strange network problems. If the "installed" is listed as 1.9.2., your installation is strange :)

Verify that the PEAR version you are using is the same you are trying to upgrade:

```
$ which pear
/usr/bin/pear
$ pear list pear|grep bin
script /usr/bin/pear
script /usr/bin/peardev
script /usr/bin/pecl
```

If they do not match, fix your include path to include the correct pear version, or the pear configuration by using

```
$ pear config-show
$ pear config-get bin_dir
$ pear config-set bin_dir /path/to/my/bin
```

and force-upgrade to install the files to the correct locations:

```
$ pear upgrade -f pear
```